# Tensorflow c api trace data

Tags: tensorflow, profiler, c-api

I wanted to know how can I get FULL_TRACE Data from Session run using C API Tensorflow. 
My problem is I found python example  but I don't know how to implement it with C API .

python example :

## Run the graph with full trace option

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
    run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
    sess.run(res, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

    # Create the Timeline object, and write it to a json
    tl = timeline.Timeline(run_metadata.step_stats)
    ctf = tl.generate_chrome_trace_format()
    with open('timeline.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(ctf)
```

C API function.

TF_CAPI_EXPORT extern void TF_SessionRun(

```
TF_Session* session,
// RunOptions
const TF_Buffer* run_options,
// Input tensors
const TF_Output* inputs, TF_Tensor* const* input_values, int ninputs,
// Output tensors
const TF_Output* outputs, TF_Tensor** output_values, int noutputs,
// Target operations
const TF_Operation* const* target_opers, int ntargets,
// RunMetadata
TF_Buffer* run_metadata,
// Output status
TF_Status*);
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask, how to put options to your TF_SessionRun.
This is a work-around to extract them from Python and use them in C-API.

PYTHON

```
runOptions = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
runConfig = tf.ConfigProto(run_options=runOptions) # run_options?
runConfSer = [int(i) for in in runConfig.SerializeToString()] # -> <runConfSer>
```

C-API

```
TF_SessionOptions* sess_opts = TF_NewSessionOptions();
uint8_t configProto[] = { <runConfSer> }; // <= <runConfSer>
size_t configProtoLen = sizeof(configProto) / sizeof(uint8_t);
TF_SetConfig(sess_opts, configProto, configProtoLen, status);
assert(TF_GetCode(status) == TF_OK);
TF_Session* session = TF_NewSession(graph, sess_opts, status);
assert(TF_GetCode(status) == TF_OK);
TF_SessionRun(session, nullptr,
                &inputs[0], &input_values[0], inputs.size(),
                &outputs[0], &output_values[0], outputs.size(),
                nullptr, 0, nullptr, status);
```

Comment: if the answer was helpful, do not hesitate to upvote it ; )    
(or did you do it like that before - then ignore this)

Comment: I figure it out before.  Using FULL_TRACE causing bad performance on android .